# Sentiment prediction using glm

Tags: r, glm, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to predict sentiments using glm and ran into following problem

```
  train_data_df <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(train_data))
  log_model <- glm(sentiment ~ word_count, data = train_data_df,   family = binomial)
     > Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

The data structure for the inputs "sentiment" and "word_count" are as follows

```
> str(train_data$sentiment[1:2])
List of 2
 $ : num 1
 $ : num 1
> str(train_data$word_count[1:2])
List of 2
 $ :List of 1
  ..    $ :Classes 'term_frequency', 'integer'  Named int [1:24] 3 1 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 3 ...
      .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:24] "and" "bags" "came" "disappointed" ...
 $ :List of 1
  ..    $ :Classes 'term_frequency', 'integer'  Named int [1:22] 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:22] "and" "anyone" "bed" "comfortable" ...



head(train_data_df[1,])
                   name
2 Planetwise Wipe Pouch
                                                                                                                                                          review
2 it came early and was not disappointed. i love planet wise bags and now my wipe holder. it keps my osocozy wipes moist and does not leak. highly recommend it.
  rating
2      5
                                                                                                                                                review_clean
2 it came early and was not disappointed i love planet wise bags and now my wipe holder it keps my osocozy wipes moist and does not leak highly recommend it
                                                              word_count sentiment
2 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1         1
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out

Comment: pls include the results of `head(train_data_df)`; also, please keep only the relevant line for `log_model` and delete the other one

Comment: @desertnaut. Thanks for pointing out the duplicate 'log_model line'. I have deleted it.

Comment: @desertnaut I have also included the results of head(train_data_df). Since the results dump is quite big I have shown the results of only the first row.

Comment: If the answer has been helpful, kindly accept it - thanks

Comment: @desertnaut .Your pointing out word_count is a list was helpful. Thanks. However I used unlist(word_count) to get over the problem.

Comment: Good - the sum I suggested was only one possible exmple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an R formula like the one you use, `sentiment ~ word_count`, each side is expected to be a single number or factor per row (this is what `'x' must be atomic` means). This is obviously not the case with your `word_count` column - it appears that, for each row, `word_count` is a list consisting of several integer values (`Have you called 'sort' on a list?` - well, indeed you have).

To confirm that this is the source of your issue, you can replace `word_count` with the sum of its elements; this should make the code to work (of course, if the result will be of any real value for sentiment prediction, it is another story, but this is not your actual question here...)